# change css with javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've seen so many different ways to do this and long story short, this is what I am using. Which appears to work for other people and not for me. Any ideas of a different way to write this?

Current CSS

```
.aw-widget-current-inner div.aw-widget-content a.aw-current-weather p span.aw-temperature-today b {
     margin: 0px !important;
 }
```

WHAT I WANT IS

```
.aw-widget-current-inner div.aw-widget-content a.aw-current-weather p span.aw-temperature-today b {
     margin: 20px;
 }
```

and here's the JS

```
<script>
    $(init);
      function init() {
        $('.aw-widget-current-inner b').css({
                'margin':'20px 0px -10px 0px'
        });
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: The JS will not change the css "file" itself but will add inline css to the element.

Comment: Also, be sure that the widget is loaded into page before you execute your `init()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`!important` overrides inline styles created with `.css()` function. Remove `!important` in your CSS and styling with jQuery should work.

Comment: The "WHAT I WANT IS" section does not have `!important`. I assume this is what the OP has tried.

Comment: Possible. The three code samples basically show diffrent things.

Comment: the whole point of using JQuery is to everse the inline !important. Obviously, deleting the inline !important would work. And if I could do that, I would not need JQ either. I could simply change the css ;) Unfortunately, this inline is in a remote file that I can not get to.

Comment: Well, using external CSS files with `!important` rule leaves you out of control. Why not use custom styles instead? Something for you to consider.

Comment: I would if I could, but the HTML is also remote. It's a pain in the butt I tell ya. I don't know how they expect me to do this without any control

Answer (score 0):

Since the original css contains "!important" it doesn't allow javascript overrides this way. You can use cssText however:

```
$('.aw-widget-current-inner b').css('cssText', 'margin:20px 0px -10px 0px !important');
```

And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbjcH/